# JS: Replace some fields of an specific object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got an object array which looks like this:

```
const items = [
  {_id: "Tk2dc3fq99qZ7YdQQ", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "one", context: "default"}
  {_id: "uK4MYJJGa6ra9e99v", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "two", context: "default"}
]
```

*Note: items is readonly as it comes from prop in a react component*

And I want to update the content by a given object like this:

```
const changeThis = { _id: "uK4MYJJGa6ra9e99v", context: "info" }
```

So the object with the matching ID should get 'info' as new context value while keeping all other elements:

```
[
  {_id: "Tk2dc3fq99qZ7YdQQ", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "one", context: "default"}
  {_id: "uK4MYJJGa6ra9e99v", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "two", context: "info"}
]
```

**Another example**

And...

```
const changeThis = { _id: "uK4MYJJGa6ra9e99v", context: "info", content: "new" }
```

...should change context and content of the matching object:

```
[
  {_id: "Tk2dc3fq99qZ7YdQQ", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "one", context: "default"}
  {_id: "uK4MYJJGa6ra9e99v", parent: "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", content: "new", context: "info"}
]
```

**My attempt**

So first of all I would use `map()` to iterate throught the array, but how do I update all other fields using `changeThis`-object?
I tried to use `assign()` and `keys()` and I tried to ignore the _id-key:

```
items.map((item, index) => {
  if (item._id === changeThis._id) {
    Object.assign(
      {},
      ...Object.keys(item).map(k => (
        {
          [k]: changeThis.indexOf(k) > -1 && k !== '_id'
            ? changeThis[k]
            : item[k]
        }
    ))
  }
});
```

Comment: why not `if (..) Object.assign(item, changeThis)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple function will suffice here; keep in mind that you will need to use `let` or `var` instead of `const` for `items`; map does not edit in place, but rather returns a new array. You could edit in place, but I would not necessarily recommend it.

```
items = items.map(item => {
  return (item._id === changeThis._id) ?
    { ...item, ...changeThis } :
    item
});
```

By spreading the contents of `changeThis` into the object after the keys of `item`, any keys appearing in `changeThis` will override those from `item`. Keys non-duplicate keys from either object will also appear in the final result.

Comment: A one-liner with... four lines? ;)

Comment: I had had it in one line, and then realized it wasn't readable at all... I'll edit that, thanks 